# Set/Remove localStorage item and EventListener

Tags: javascript, local-storage, event-listener

I have been messing with localStorage and EventListener as seen below (from w3schools but with my messing around). The below always prints "A change was made in the storage area 3" to the div. I'm guessing this is the asynchronous nature of JS and I'd have to do something like promise chaining?

Secondly, and similarly, when I add removing the variable from localStorage and therefore, in EventListener, detecting that the variable is null, the below will not print anything to the div. i'm presuming it's seeing the removal before it can execute the first event (setting the variable) where it actually prints. Anyway, is there a way to pull off setting and removing a variable from localStorage or is this all that asynch stuff and needs promises (formerly callbacks and setTimeouts)? Thank you very much.

```
<button onclick="changeValue()">Change a Storage Item</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

    window.addEventListener("storage", myFunction);
    var x;
    var c=0;
    var mtv;
    function myFunction(event) {
      if (event.key==="mytime") {
        mtv=localStorage.getItem("mytime");
          if (mtv===null) {

            } else {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "A change was made in the storage area "+ c;
          }
        }
    }

    function changeValue() {
      x = window.open("", "myWindow", "width=200,height=100");
      c=c+1
      x.localStorage.setItem("mytime", "true");
      c=c+1;
      x.localStorage.removeItem("mytime");
      c=c+1;
      x.close();
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE...I don't know how to format code in a response but instead of doing the above instant removal of the localStorage object, I went with an add/remove toggle on the localStorage variable...the adding or removal should trigger the ActionListener event in the grandparent window....

```
if(localStorage.getItem('mytime')){
      x.localStorage.removeItem("mytime");
}else{
      x.localStorage.setItem("mytime", "true");
}
```

Comment: why are you using `window.open` at all?

Comment: w3schools had it  in their sandbox and it's sorta what I'm trying to do.... triggering a refresh of the grandparent window from the grandchild sans the parent (in case the parent is closed, then the opener link is lost).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the easier that you can do to see what happen is create an HTML with your code and open in your browser. Then, put breakpoints in the event and in the places in which you update the storage. Let's see:

- Click on button
- Open a window (useless because that window do nothing)
- Update the storage (no event fire yet)
- Remove the storage (no event fire yet)
- Close the window
- Now, you receive the 2 events with your c=3 in both cases

If you need track your c values, you can save in the storage that values:

```
x.localStorage.setItem("mytime", c);
```

Then, you receive a first event with event.newValue="1" and a second one with event.newValue=null and event.oldValue="1".

Comment: I will work through that. The c's are just a way to track the process, it's really an on/off thing, or add/remove variable, just to trigger the onstorage event in a grandparent window. now that i'm having a problem with.

Comment: You can use the close window event to remove the item of the storage instead of do all in the same moment

Comment: Ok, yeah, that's what I was going for. I pretty much have this cncept down but my issue is that I'm doing this in Lotus Notes. For some reason, the same markup on a notes page refuses to register and/or detect the storage change.  window.onstorage=function(e) {... is totally ignored. It all works if I put the exact same markup in the w3schools sandbox. I can't figure it out and it's driving me up the wall.